# SQL Get cases related to a user and the number of files attached to that case

Tags: sql, join, count

Hi everyone got a little stuck on an sql query. I have four tables

```
    users
    +----+------------+-----------+--------+
    | id | first_name | last_name | active |
    +----+------------+-----------+--------+
    |  1 | Joe        | Bloggs    |      1 |
    |  2 | John       | Doe       |      1 |
    |  3 | Dave       | Smith     |      1 |
    +----+------------+-----------+--------+

    cases
        +----+-----------+-------------+
        | id | case_code |  case_name  |
        +----+-----------+-------------+
        |  1 | THEC12C   | Test Case 1 |
        |  2 | ABCD23A   | Test Case 2 |
        +----+-----------+-------------+

case_creditors
        +----+---------+-------------+
        | id | case_id | creditor_id |
        +----+---------+-------------+
        |  1 |       1 |           3 |
        |  2 |       2 |           1 |
        +----+---------+-------------+

    case_files
    +----+---------+----------+-----------+
    | id | case_id | filename | file type |
    +----+---------+----------+-----------+
    |  1 |       1 | test.pdf | pfd       |
    |  2 |       2 | file.txt | txt       |
    |  3 |       2 | word.doc | doc       |
    +----+---------+----------+-----------+
```

When a user logs in i need to show a table with the users accociated cases the number of files attached to that case so if Joe Blogs loged in head see the following table

```
+-----------+-------------+-------+
| Case Code |  Case Name  | Files |
+-----------+-------------+-------+
| ABCD23A   | Test Case 2 |     2 |
+-----------+-------------+-------+
```

ive been trying to write the sql statement to do this but am getting stuck on the query and wandered if someone could help give me some pointers. the sql ive gor so far

```
SELECT * FROM cases 
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM case_files WHERE case_files.case_id = cases.id) as Files 
JOIN case_creditors ON cases.id = case_creditors.case_id   
WHERE case_creditors.creditor_id = 1
```

Comment: It looks like there may be missing a relationship of one table or two. Well, either that, OR, your WHERE clause does not make sense if you want to return a Files count of 2. It should have been WHERE case_files.case_id=2. OR, the missing reference is the user_id in the case_files.

Comment: hi dal789 id dont want the files to be associated with a user but only a case. Evert case can have many users and many files so i didn't think i needed a relationship between files and users

Answer (score 0, accepted):

managed to sort this with

```
SELECT
    ips_case.*,
    COUNT(case_files.file_id) AS Files
FROM
    ips_case
    LEFT JOIN case_files ON ips_case.id = case_files.case_id
    JOIN case_creditors ON ips_case.id = case_creditors.case_id
WHERE
    case_creditors.creditors_id = 4
GROUP BY
    ips_case.id
```